# Need help DB Query for this scenario

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I am unable to derive a SQL query for the following table content.

[image]

When i tried below query i am getting above said output. Can someone help me to give the required query for it.

```
select Name, count(Status) from mytable where Status='Open' group by mytable union
select Name, count(Status) from mytable where Status='Cleared' group by mytable
```

Comment: Use case expressions in the select list to do conditional aggregation.

Answer (score 2):

Use `case` expressions in the select list to do conditional aggregation.

```
select Name,
       count(case when Status = 'Open' then 1 end) as opencnt,
       count(case when Status = 'Cleared' then 1 end) as clearedcnt
from mytable
where Status in ('Open', 'Cleared')
group by Name
```

`COUNT()` counts non-null values. The `case` expressions above returns null when the conditions aren't fulfilled.

Comment: should it be `group by Name` instead of `group by mytable` ?

Comment: Double thanks Jarlh, as i dont have much exp in SQL, i never get a chance to use case along with count. This could be really a nice trick though. Thanks for your reply.